# how to set subgraph width in graphviz?

Tags: graphviz

I am drawing a graphic using this:

```
digraph G {
  subgraph cluster_redisObject{
    style="rounded";
    bgcolor="#028d35";

    type [label="数据类型(Type)",style=rounded,shape=box];
    encoding [label="编码类型(Encoding)",style=rounded,shape=box]
  }
}
```

The object arrange herizon,

[image]

How to make subgraph element arrangement by verticle(up&down)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply add an invisible edge between those nodes, for example:

```
type -> encoding [style = invis]
```

Comment: it works,did you know how to control the two element vertical distance?@marapet

Comment: @Dolphin You can try using [`ranksep`](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/attrs.html#d:ranksep)